# Aggregation on nested documents mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

i have 2 different collections on mongodb collection1_dcoument and package. And ı using this 2 doc. nested type. for example

```
collection1_document_example:

{
_id:ObjectId('624a0573723d2c1eb3113844'),
'package': {
        _id: ObjectId('5f52253487fb8e001184f414'),
        name: 'Custom Package',
        package_id: 'custom',
}
```

and I need a query that groups on this collection based on the package_id value inside

Comment: What is your expected output? What you've described isn't a valid document.

Comment: ım sorry for this, ı didnt write whole document ,all docs contain package docs and I need a grouping by these package names

Comment: package is a nested document? not collection like this: { ..., package: [{...}, {...}] }?